# Spring Security Authentication Every X Minutes (Without Killing Session)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am interested in asking users to re-authenticate after 15 mins of inactivity without killing their session (session life is longer).

Is there a way to specify an authentication timeout within Spring Security that would accomplish this automatically or some cleaver way I can accomplish this without too much effort?

Comment: You can do a request filter that logs them out if it's been more than 15 minutes since they've logged in.

Comment: Yes, a filter where I check the last accessed time of the session is feasible. However, I am wondering if I can leverage something built into Spring Security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a request filter seems to be the best way to achieve this goal. In order to prevent the loss of data, I chose to have a blocking popup that displays if the session has been inactive. This way I can refresh the page and the user is right where they left off instead of needing to store the initial request and having to find it and redirect them.